# Make Smart GWT SectionStack close older sections when space is filled?

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, smartgwt

I'm currently using SmartGWT's SectionStack. I have eight SectionStackSections for this stack. I have the VisibilityMode set to MULTIPLE. Inside each section is a block of text that can vary widely in size. Right now, if I expand all the sections and the content exceeds the height of the stack, it will not be visible. I know I could add scroll bars, but I don't want that. What I'd like is for the older open sections to be closed when the expanding of a new section would exceed the total height of the stack. Does anyone have an idea as to how I could go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I've last used SmartGwt but adding [SectionHeaderClickHandlers](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/layout/events/HasSectionHeaderClickHandlers.html) by `sectionStack.addSectionHeaderClickHandler(..)` you can keep track of which and how many of sections are expanded, perhaps the total height of them (depending on your approach really..) in a variable, and in the same handler evaluate and collapse necessary sections using sectionStack's `sectionStack.collapseSection(..)` method

Comment: I'll try this out soon and see if it works out for me. Thanks for the idea.